# How to create a user Environment variable that *calls* %date% or %time% each time it's invoked?

Tags: date, time, batch-file, environment-variables, expand

I'm trying to create 2 user environment variables with the following defintion:

```
datel=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
datetime=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

so that every time I call:

```
echo %datel%
echo %datetime%
```

I get:

```
20110407
20110407-11_45_45
```

I can define the user environment variables without problems in the GUI (Computer->(Right Click)Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables) and when I do a "set" in a new cmd window I get the following:

```
>set da  
datel=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
datetime=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

But then "echoing" them is not what I expected:

```
C:\Users\jaravj
>echo %datel%
%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%

C:\Users\jaravj
>echo %datetime%
%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

Thanks a huge lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `call echo %datel%` which results in another parsing pass (which you need here). `echo` by itself will not expand any environment variables, that does the shell upon parsing a line. Therefore you need to force that.

That's undocumented, however, so take that with a grain of salt. A more robust (i.e. actually supported) option might be to use a subroutine:

```
:expand
  echo.%*
goto :eof
```

and then call it with

```
call :expand echo %datel%
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use the delayed expansion, then you are able to expands two times in one line.

```
setlocal
set "datel=!date:~-4!!date:~3,2!!date:~0,2!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %datel%
```

It's works because, first the batch line parser expands `%datel%` to `!date:~-4!!date:~3,2!!date:~0,2!` and after all percent expansions are done.

Then the escape characters are handled, and then as the last phase the parser expands the exclamations are expanded.

Explained in [how cmd.exe parse scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)