# Dynamic nested environment variable in batch

Tags: dynamic, batch-file, environment-variables

I'd like to have log with prepend of time and username, but I haven't been able to get %TIME% and %DATE% to dynamically be evaluated. I've tried many versions of using "!", but I've never gotten it to work. What I'd like is to have

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set nameDateTime=!%USERNAME% %DATE% %TIME%!
echo %nameDateTime%
echo %nameDateTime%
echo %nameDateTime%
EndLocal
```

to produce 3 different times (assuming they're done far enough apart). 
I tried the second answer in: [How to create a user Environment variable that *calls* %date% or %time% each time it's invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579213/how-to-create-a-user-environment-variable-that-calls-date-or-time-each-tim), but when I call echo %date1%, it just prints out date1, while set date1 prints out the whole !date1..! line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already use delayedExpansion:

```
@echo off
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set nameDateTime=!USERNAME! !DATE! !TIME!
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %nameDateTime%
echo %nameDateTime%
echo %nameDateTime%
EndLocal
```

You will need to time space those echos to see they actually print different values

Comment: when I run: echo %nameDateTime% I get !USERNAME! !DATE! !TIME! as the output.

Comment: @dale Above work only in batch. Do you want to run it directly from cmd line?

Comment: no, I don't need it to work on cmd line, just didn't run it that way.

Comment: Thanks @wmz, it worked, I'm guessing I had stuff that would have worked, I just didn't use a batch file.

Comment: @dale Another possibility (this would also work from cmd if started with `cmd /v:on`) with delayed expansion enabled, you could escape `!`: `set "nameDateTime=^!USERNAME^! ^!DATE^! ^!TIME^!"` (mind quotes).

Comment: @wmz Exactly when you use `%username%` it will fail if it contains `!`.  With `!username!` it will work always.

Comment: @jeb You're right I have not thought it well :( Thanks for pointing that out.  I will delete it.

Comment: @dale - Disregard my previous comment, it was wrong I will delete it. See jebs comment (he is correct)